# Game theory formula explanation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

I'm a psychology undergrad that is doing an essay on cohesiveness and cooperative games. What does the following formula mean? What does each component mean?

v(N) ≥ v(S) for all S ⊆ N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the value when all players cooperate is at least as large as the value of a few players when they cooperate.

The ⊆ symbol is to indicate a subset.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. So the characteristic function (v) is the value and S would represent few players?

Comment: @John $S$ is anywhere between zero and all players (zero and all including).

Comment: Wait, I think I got it, v(S) would represent the value of all players participating, and v(N) is the value of the few that participate?

Comment: the other way around, the value of all players is never less than the value of $S$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @John just accept the answer if it satisfactorily answered your question

Comment: Could you break down this formula: v : 2N → R≥0

Comment: @John it means that v takes as input a set of players, and outputs a nonnegative number.